# How to display line numbers in new gnome-text-editor

Tags: 23.04, gnome-text-editor

Is there a way to show line numbers in new gnome-text-editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the settings 'cog' in the titlebar to open the menu. Select "Show Line Numbers" from the menu.

[image: Menu in GNOME Text Editor]

Comment: I can see it now :facepalm:

Answer (score 0):

I'll just update this because I know it's not there in what is called Text Edit 42.0 on a Fedora live I was using, which linked to gnome-text-editor on Github. It wasn't in the hamburger menu and it wasn't in the gear icon menu. There was yet another icon, a box with a wrench in it. It was there.

Comment: Please say which Ubuntu version this also applies to.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1339797)